# NullPointerException at onFilterTouchEventForSecurity

Tags: android

I have an app published and this crash appears for me but i never catch it in debug no matter what i do i try all scenarios and i looked for causes nothing appears any help below the log i have GCM youtube AdMob SDKS.

Here is the crash code:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void imv.a(boolean)' on a null object reference
   at ilr.onFilterTouchEventForSecurity(SourceFile:115)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1942)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2450)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1758)
   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2854)
   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2389)
   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8667)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4364)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4189)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3722)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3785)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3741)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3868)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3749)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3925)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3722)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3785)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3741)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3749)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3722)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6058)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6032)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6003)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6148)
   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:218)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:150)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5473)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
```

Comment: It is probably related to YouTube. I started seeing this crash after adding the YouTube API. Still searching for solutions.

Comment: facing  the same issue.Please post if you have got the answer.

Comment: Same here. If you found the solution please let us know.

Comment: Did you find a solution please?

Comment: Getting the same crash. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: yes it should be related to YouTube Android Player API https://github.com/youtube/yt-android-player/issues/22

Comment: @user2970035 do you use YouTube Android Player API in your app?